# jQuery indexedDB - return true if record found

Tags: jquery, return, promise, indexeddb

i want to write a function which checks if a defined value exists in the IndexedDB using the jQuery Plugin.

I tried using this, but it dont work because the return found is executed before the promise.done() finishes. How can i solve this?

Thanks a lot.

```
function equipmentHasOrder(equipment) {
var orderObjectStore = $.indexedDB("order").objectStore("openOrders");
var found = false;

var index = orderObjectStore.index("EQUIPMENT");
var promise = index.get(equipment);

promise.done(function (result, event) {
    if(result !== undefined) {
        found = true;
    }
});

return found;

promise.fail(function (error, event) {
    error; // Type of error that has occured
    event; // Error event
    event.type; // indicates if there was an error or an exception
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the promise with `then`:

```
function equipmentHasOrder(equipment){
    var orderObjectStore = $.indexedDB("order").objectStore("openOrders");

    var index = orderObjectStore.index("EQUIPMENT");
    var promise = index.get(equipment);

    // note the `.then` for chaining and the fact we're returning it.
    return promise.then(function (result) {
        return (result !== undefined);
    });
}
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
equipmentHasOrder(equipment).then(function(result){
     if(result){ // found

     } else { // handle not found

     }
});
```

Comment: Good morning, so i see it is not possible with the indexedDB to write a function which returs just true if record was found and false if not found because of the asynchronous behaviour right?